# Why won't hotmail let me include a name in addition to my email address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, spam, hotmail

I'm trying to send emails from my Ruby on Rails application, and whenever I use the following format: `Jon Doe <jdoe@mydomain.com>`, Hotmail marks the email as spam.  However, when I use `jdoe@mydomain.com` without the name, it goes through fine.  Anybody know how to get around this so my emails don't get sent to spam for hotmail users?

I have SPF set up on my DNS and I'm sending from the SPF verified server if that's of any help.

Thanks!

Comment: I also just added DomainKeys and it still does the exact same thing…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you specifying the pretty name in the MAIL FROM or in the header? In the MAIL FROM, you're only supposed to include the mailbox address itself, according to RFC 2821. Most mail servers will tolerate the pretty-from there too, but Hotmail may be using that as a spam signal.